# Unable to copy updated file from sub folder using xcopy

Tags: batch-file

```
set "source=C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\msword"
set "dest=D:\Test"

pushd "%source%" ||(
   echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
   'dir /A-D /OD /B') Do set "file=%%f"

popd

xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\%file%" "%dest%\"
```

Above script not copying sub folders files. What should I modify?

i want to script that copy current date created file and any previous file updated on the same day to other drive folder including with same directory structure. But it should only stored current date and update files ......

***Updated script (as requested by @BaliC)***

```
set "source=C:\Documents and Settings\kalim\My Documents\msword"
set "dest=D:\Test"
pushd "%source%" || ( echo.Source does not exist & pause & goto EOF)
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\" "%dest%\"
)
```

Comment: Although you seem to be requesting a list of file (with the `dir /A-D /OD /B`), you are storing only one name, probably the last one in the list. And you are running `xcopy` just once, for the last stored name. Could that be your issue? As for that last name, it *should* copy all files with that name from the subfolders. (It did for me in my tests anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Andriy correctly pointed out, you are looping over the output of the `dir` command, and setting the file each time without doing anything with it, so it just keeps overwriting the variable with the next file, so you are left with the last file in the output.

This should work

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
set file=%%f
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\%file%" "%dest%"
)
```

When testing I did have an error about cyclic copying when using the `/e` switch on files, but just see if this works first.

Also just for future reference, the `/e` switch is the same as `/s /e`, so you don't need the `/s`.

***Update***

The reason your script wasn't copying the files is because there were trailing slashes on the source and dest paths, which `xcopy` doesn't like, and it won't recognize them as paths.

Just remove them and it works like a charm :)

```
set "source=C:\Documents and Settings\kalim\My Documents\msword"
set "dest=D:\Test"
pushd "%source%" || ( echo.Source does not exist & pause & goto EOF)
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%" "%dest%"
)
```

Comment: Try putting a `pause` at the end and see if it gives you any errors?

Comment: i want to script that copy current date created file and any previous file updated on the same day to other drive folder including with same directory structure. But it should only stored current date and update files ......

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
set file=%%f
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\%file%" "%dest%"
)           this script show invalid path ....but when i ran above scripts of mine it works fine..

Comment: The only difference between our scripts is you have a trailing slash on the end of your `%dest%`, not sure if it will make a difference, but try %dest%\ instead.

Comment: Could you post the whole script you are using now into your question so I can have a look? It's much easier to see where it's going wrong visually.

Comment: set "source=C:\Documents and Settings\kalim\My Documents\msword"
set "dest=D:\Test"

pushd "%source%" ||(
   echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do (
xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\" "%dest%\"
)

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do ( xcopy /s /d /e "%source%" "%dest%" ) but above command copying all the files and subdirectories including older files..

Comment: Bali ..... i want the script to backup the latest file of the paticular day and any older file which has been edited on the same day should be copy to other folder with a same directories structure.......  And thanks for answering.

Comment: robocopy "C:\Documents and Settings\kalim\My Documents\msword" "D:\Test" /s /maxage:1 i have just added /s and it done the magic i really appreciated you for giving me your time and thanks a lot..

Comment: The above robocopy command copy the day older file on modified date basis, can i copy file on created date rather than on modified date...